# Embedded Ethereum Wallet

Tags: wallets, embedded

Is there any embedded wallet library available for Ethereum I can use for the IoT devices (Raspberry Pi, Arduino etc)? I want something similar to MetaMask but, instead of holding the wallet addresses, public keys and private keys in the web broswer I want to hold them directly to the device and be able to make transactions.

Answer (score 4):

[RaspNode](https://raspnode.com/diyEthereumGeth.html#installdependencies) has a good way of getting started for the RaspberryPi.
Your steps, assuming you've configured it for networking, are:

- Downloading and installing dependencies
- Downloading and installing Geth
- Configure and run Geth
- Configure home network to sync up with
  the Ethereum network

Arduinos and other microcontrollers don't meet the hardware specifications to act as a full node. You could get around this by using [Infura](https://infura.io/) and a device specific library like [Web3-arduino](https://github.com/kopanitsa/web3-arduino).

Comment: Suppose the device is resource-constrained and I am using Infura(Infura only gives api keys to connect to the node) and Web3. How can I establish blockchain identity(wallet addresses, PubKeys, PrKeys) embbedded on the device?

Comment: @Njabulo Is this an arduino? https://hackernoon.com/building-your-own-ethereum-hardware-wallet-for-5-c85fe7405276

Comment: I don't understand the point, nor the security of doing so. If you are comfortable with microcontrollers and would like to work towards something supported by the academic community, check out the STM32 with secure elements. It's what's used in the ledgers I believe and it's an industry standard.

Comment: Thank you @Vignesh. This was useful.

Comment: Sure thing. Following my github would be appreciated! :)